# How to create an SVG path from an object in vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, svg, charts

I have an object like this:

```js
{
  12: 46,
  15: 50,
  18: 42,
  21: 45,
  24: 32
}
```

I want to create a simple svg path with just pure javascript and no additional libraries.

The result must be like below, with the with and height adjusted to the maximum values and the path representing the objects values:

```
<svg width="..." height="..."><path d="M ..."></path></svg>
```

I tried the following code:

```
function CreateChart(data) {
    var result = 'M ';
    var array_values = Object.values(data);
    for(var i=1;i<array_values.length;i++){
        result += array_values[i][1]+ ' '+array_values[i][1]+' '
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is creating the path string (the `d` attribute). You can do this in vanilla JS like so:

```
const coords = [
    [12, 46],
    [15, 50],
    [18, 42],
    [21, 45],
    [24, 32],
];
let d = "";
let width = 0;
let height = 0;
for (x in coords) {
    d += d === "" ? "M" : " L";
    d += `${coords[x][0]} ${coords[x][1]}`;
    maxX = Math.max(width, x);
    maxY = Math.max(height, coords[x]);
}
```

Now you have your path (`"M12 46 L15 50 L18 42 L21 45 L24 32"`) and your width and height. Just create an svg element and set the width and height. Then create a path, set it's `d` attribute to the `d` variable and append it to the svg element.

Comment: Why put L commands in there? Just have a single M at the start then add the numbers as co-ordinate pairs.

Comment: @RobertLongson Good point. They don't seem neccesary, but I do think they make for better readability.

Comment: @AxelKöhler, I would absolutely refrain from using an object to store ordinate pairs, as property ordering isn't part of the ECMAScript specification. Thus, relying on property ordering can result in unexpected behaviors. I'd suggest using an array of tuples, instead; like this:

    [
        [12, 46],
        [15, 50]
    ]

Comment: @DavideCannizzo Good point, I have updated the code of my solution. Another upside is that an x-coordinate can be re-used.